# JSON error when running react native app with expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, mobile-application

When I try to run my react native app on expo with `expo start`, it logs the qr code, but it also logs this error after some time:

```
Failed to construct transformer: Error: Ca
nnot parse /home/runner/kitsu-mobile-1/.nvm
/test/fast/Unit tests/mocks/project_dirs/ne
sted-both/package.json as JSON: Unexpected
end of JSON input
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/kit
su-mobile-1/node_modules/metro/node_modules
/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:167:15)
...
```

I cannot connect after scanning the qr code with my phone because of that error.

I am using:

- node 16.2.0
- npm 7.13.0

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late answer, but seems we are the only 2 that had this error.

If you fill the package.json that give this error with `{}`, the error disappears!